# Proof that a certain subset of the reals is not a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $A = \{x \sin x : x \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subset \mathbb{R}$. Is $A$ a ring under the usual addition and multiplication operations of $\mathbb{R}$? It looks like it's not, but I can't find something concrete to justify this.

Comment: Under *what operations* ? The usual ones in $\;\Bbb R\;$ ?

Comment: Point taken. Will edit.

Comment: Is this even closed under negation? After all, $(-x)\sin(-x) = x\sin x$ because $\sin x = -\sin (-x)$...

Comment: It's not immediately clear why there isn't some $y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $y\sin{y}=-x\sin{x}$ though (I agree that this is unlikely).

Comment: To me it seems hard to refute any closure claims.

Comment: To take things even further (and actually possibly point to a proof): is there even one non-trivial identity among some finite number of members of $A$?

Comment: @Steven: $\sin n$ is a polynomial in $\sin 1$ whenever $n$ is odd.

Comment: Another identity is that $f(1 \sin 1, 2 \sin 2) = 0$ where $$f(x,y) = y^2 - 8 x^2 (1-x^2) (1-2x^2)^2$$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose $A$ were a ring; then in particular, we have $2\sin 1=n\sin n$ for some $n$.  Now, use the duplication formulas for $\sin$ to write $\sin n$ as $(\sin 1)\cdot P_n(\cos 1)$, where $P_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ (this can be shown straightforwardly via induction; these polynomials are known as the [*Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html)).  This yields an identity of the form $nP_n(\cos 1)-2=0$, contradicting the fact that $\cos 1$ is transcendental.  In fact, this shows that no non-trivial linear relation can hold among any finite number of members of $A$.

Comment: Could you at least hint at a justification of the last sentence?

Comment: @MannyReyes I should correct that to 'additive identity', actually (I was thinking of $A$ as a group, not a ring).  The proof in that case is almost identical: use the $\sin n$ identity to write each of the terms in the form $(\sin 1)\cdot P_n(\cos 1)$, sum, and derive a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, the "additive identity" helps a lot.  So it seems that you're actually proving that $\{\sin(n) \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linearly independent subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  Very nice!

Comment: (Note that similarly to a now-deleted answer from @MarcinŁoś, this uses the Lindemann-Weirstraß theorem to derive its conclusion - in my case, it's implicit in the assertion that $\cos 1$ is transcendental.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no 1 (multiplicative identity) so it is not a ring. x sin(x) is either 0 (when x=0) or is a transcendental number due to [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Transcendence_of_e_and_.CF.80) when x <> 0

Comment: Depends on your definition of a ring. Rings are not usually required to have an identity though.

Comment: True that is unclear from the question if they mean ring with identity or not. The other answer also assumes there is a 1 in the ring when it say there is an n such that 2 sin 1 = n sin n. Because the 2 here is an element 2 in the ring to multiply 1 sin 1 by. Hence it assumes there is a 1 in the ring to make the element 2 from.

Comment: Now I am curious if you assume that there is not a 1 in the ring if you can still prove the statement :-)

Comment: I think that Steven's answer tackles closure of addition, i.e. whether $1\sin 1 + 1 \sin 1 = 2\sin 1$ is an element of this set or not.

Comment: Aha I had missed that point. Thanks for explaining! So given we are using the 1 from R here in regular way it seems like we must be assuming the ring has identity.

Comment: But the unity element of a subring need not be the same as that of the ambient ring, assuming the said identity exists. I hope I haven't misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks for clarifying. Now I get that 2 sin(1) is just 1 sin(1) + 1 sin(1) and Steven showed the set is not closed under addition.